# How to make Java display box-drawing characters? I get question marks

Tags: encoding

At my Win10 CmdPrompt, the 'chcp' command returns: "Active code page: 437".
I think CodePage_437 has box-drawing characters starting around 180 or so.
I wrote a tiny program to display chars 0-255, but get no box-drawing chars.

```
public class CodePage_437 { 
/* Display all 256 glyphs in a 16x16 matrix */

public static void displayAllGlyphs() {
    int  c = 0;
    for (    int y = 0;  y < 16;  y++) {
        for (int x = 0;  x < 16;  x++) {        
            System.out.format("%3d",   c  );
            System.out.format("%2c  ", c++);
    }
        System.out.format("\n");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayAllGlyphs();
    System.out.format("---EOJ---\n");
}
```

}

I get the same output in the Eclipse 2020-12 Console pane, as in a CmpPrompt
window.  It looks like an encoding problem and I must have tried 10 suggested
solutions, but none worked.

Comment: _Box Drawings_  present in `cp437` are Unicode `'\u2500 \u2502 \u250C \u2510 \u2514 \u2518 \u251C \u2524 \u252C \u2534 \u253C \u2550 \u2551 \u2552 \u2553 \u2554 \u2555 \u2556 \u2557 \u2558 \u2559 \u255A \u255B \u255C \u255D \u255E \u255F \u2560 \u2561 \u2562 \u2563 \u2564 \u2565 \u2566 \u2567 \u2568 \u2569 \u256A \u256B \u256C'` **regardless of console encoding**…

Comment: Thank you very much, JosefZ!!  Wonderfully simple.